# Is there a way to get access to "Others Workingset" or its workingSet Manager?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt, working-set

I am recreating an explorer in eclipse which should enable working set as top layer style. Is there a way to access the "Others Workingset" created by eclipse jdt? I tried to create my own localWorkingSetManager and add a working set with the ID IWorkingSetIDs.OTHERS, but this leads to exception in OthersWorkingSetUpdater. 
If there is not a way to directly access this working set, is there any other way to create a working set that is not editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define your own working set id and use your own `IWorkingSetUpdater` if you need one.

The Java plugin defines the Others working set using:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.workingSets">
  <workingSet
        name="%OthersWorkingSetWizardPage.name"
        description="%OthersWorkingSetWizardPage.description"
        icon="$nl$/icons/full/obj16/jworkingSet_obj.png"
        updaterClass="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.workingsets.OthersWorkingSetUpdater"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.OthersWorkingSet">
  </workingSet>
</extension>
```

You will need to specify your own `updaterClass` and `id`

The key here is that no `pageClass` attribute is specified which makes the working set not editable.